# Reading chunks of a remote file without transferring the whole file?

Tags: linux, file, unix

Is it possible via any Unix utility to read chunks of a remote file (like say 'head' does) instead of transferring the whole file ?

Comment: what remote access methods are available to you?  SSH, FTP, HTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute remote commands through SSH

```
ssh user@server.com "head <filename>"
```

Comment: Thanks! That made me feel dumb myself :-(

Answer (score 1):

1. You can remotely extract interesting
   part of the file (using *dd* for
   example) and then transfer the
   interesting chunk back.
2. Other option would be to employ
   netcat:

   ```
   dd if=file skip=... bs=... count=...| nc <host> <port>
   ```

   And on the receiver:

   ```
   nc -l -p <port> | dd of=chunk
   ```
3. You can use *curl* with the
   following options (assuming you have got HTTP or FTP that supports seeking):

   - *-r* to retrieve the range of bytes
   - *-C* to start downloading from a given offset

For sure there are other possibilities apart from the ones mentioned. More information on your case could help to devise a smarter method.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand Python, the paramiko library should make this reasonably easy to do. It is a pure Python implementation of the ssh protocol, and specifically sftp should allow you to get the part of a file you need.

See http://www.lag.net/paramiko/ for details.